# Why are products appearing with sub-sub-categories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a woocommerce site with the mayashop theme. I'm trying to make product categories show as their own page without products, then you drill down to see the products. This seems to work for subcategories for me but not on a page with sub-sub-categories. Is there a setting I've missed?

[Settings to show just categories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jgjc.png)

[Problem page, the subcategory is Collections>Travel and the sub-sub-categories are the geographic regions. But the test project IN one of those regions is showing...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QrFFF.png)

Any help much appreciated. I'm happy enough with creating simple plugins etc if needed but woocommerce is too big to do this without being pointed at the right parts to change :)

Comment: A test page that has just the subcategories and not sub-sub-categories seems to work ok so that's why I suspect the issue is about depth of categorisation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue; the theme's version of archive-product.php was displaying too much.

I added a condition: if the woocommerce_product_subcategories() method output any categories, it will withold outputting posts (products). Perhaps a bit simplistic but the smallest change to my child theme to get the effect I was after.

[archive-product.php diff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq7IX.png)